# pandas set column value based on two conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame. I would like to add a new column with a value of 1 for a new column, y, if the previous value of x is less than 50 and the current value is more than 50.

I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(40,60,size=(10, 1)), columns=['x'])

df['y'] = 1 if (df['x'].shift(1) < 50) and (df['x'] > 50) else 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old story. pandas offers you an overloaded version of the bitwise operators which you should use for vectorised OR/AND operations. Anyway, based on your code, an `astype` conversion would be more appropriate here.

```
In [139]: df['y'] = ((df['x'].shift(1) < 50) & (df['x'] > 50)).astype(np.int8)

In [140]: df
Out[140]:
    x  y
0  51  0
1  51  0
2  48  0
3  54  1
4  47  0
5  41  0
6  51  1
7  49  0
8  53  1
9  41  0
```

or less common option:

```
In [146]: df.eval("(x.shift() < 50 and x > 50) * 1", inplace=False, engine='python')
Out[146]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    0
8    1
9    0
Name: x, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Sorry, out of votes. But take my explanation!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

`and` is an operator that Python classes can *not* override. It takes as input two expressions. It evaluates the first one. In case the truthiness of the first one is `True`, then it evaluates the latter and returns that result. In case the thruthiness is `False`, then it returns the result of the former expression.

What you here can use are boolean operators `&` (logical and) and `|` (logical or). We can rewrite it thus to:

```
df['y'] = ((df['x'].shift(1) < 50) & (df['x'] > 50)).astype(int)
```

Here we use `astype` to convert the row of *booleans* to a row of integers. `False` maps to `0` and `True` maps to `1`.